# C# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (Newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, http, object

How do I get this array as string? unfortunately (I am a beginner) i only know how to get only arrays or only objects but not how to "mix"

[image]

```
    public class TrackContent
    {
        [JsonProperty("track")] public Album Album { get; set; }
    }

    public class Album
    {
        [JsonProperty("album")] public CoverImage CoverImage { get; set; }
    }

    public class CoverImage
    {
        [JsonProperty("image")] public Number Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Number
    {
        [JsonProperty("3")] public ImageUrl ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class ImageUrl
    {
        [JsonProperty("#text")] public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string auth = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&artist=Ariana%20Grande&track=One%20Last%20Time&format=json";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var jsonInfo = httpClient.GetStringAsync(auth);
        var deserializeJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <TrackContent>(jsonInfo.Result);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializeJson.Album.CoverImage.Number.ImageUrl.Name);
    }
```

Comment: If that your actual API Key? If it is, I would delete the question and create a new one where it is redacted. Editing the question will not help as the history is still available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a tool such as this  http://json2csharp.com/ to generate your C# Classes from a JSON string.

This will then give you the classes you need, and you can then deserialise the "RootObject" using Newtonsoft.

Edit:
And if you want to go the other way, then this tool can be helpful
https://csharp2json.io/

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Streamable
{
    [JsonProperty("#text")] public string text { get; set; }
    public string fulltrack { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mbid { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    [JsonProperty("#text")] public string text { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class Attr
{
    public string position { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string mbid { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public List<Image> image { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@attr")] public Attr attr { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Toptags
{
    public List<Tag> tag { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mbid { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public Streamable streamable { get; set; }
    public string listeners { get; set; }
    public string playcount { get; set; }
    public Artist artist { get; set; }
    public Album album { get; set; }
    public Toptags toptags { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Track track { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var deserializeJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonInfo.Result);
Console.WriteLine(deserializeJson.Album.image[3].text);
```

> Edit:
>   That way, you can deserialize any JSON response from the API into the C# RootObject and you can access any of the properties / values you wish.

Comment: Hi Kuqs, if my solution worked, please mark it as the correct answer. I'm glad I could help